# bootstrapping mixed effect regression coefficients in statsmodels

Tags: python, statsmodels, statistics-bootstrap

I have a mixed effect model that looks like this:

```py
import statsmodels.formula.api as smf

formula = "revised_error ~ C(condition, Treatment('solo_feedback'))*round_index"

model = smf.mixedlm(forumla, data=data, groups=data['player_id']).fit()
```

Now `model.conf_int()` gets me the confidence interval for the fitted parameters based on the standard normal distribution. However, I want the bootstrapped coefficients and confidence but `model.boostrap()` throws an error:

```
AttributeError: 'MixedLMResults' object has no attribute 'endog'
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, your code has a spelling mistake which is probably causing some issues up front if you haven't corrected it: `formula`

See the note on [this page](https://www.statsmodels.org/stable/generated/statsmodels.regression.mixed_linear_model.MixedLMResults.bootstrap.html#statsmodels.regression.mixed_linear_model.MixedLMResults.bootstrap) for why this isn't working for you. This isn't natively supported as of now for complex models. However, you can get around this by doing it manually instead of using the `bootstrap` method.

You can follow [this](https://rlhick.people.wm.edu/posts/comparing-stata-and-ipython-commands-for-ols-models.html#Fitting-the-model-in-Ipython) notebook to see how it can be implemented.